# Tailwind navbar buttons don't work anytime the screen size gets smaller

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css, navbar

I'm having trouble with the buttons not working at any smaller screen size. This has been an issue in multiple navbars I've tried so I'm quite confused.

Below is my navbar code, it should work and it does at xl screensize but not at anything less.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {
  Navbar,
  Link,
  Text,
  Avatar,
  Dropdown,
  useTheme,
  createTheme,
  NextUIProvider,
  Button,
} from ' @nextui-org/react';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
import { Layout } from './NavbarHelpers/Layout.js';
import NavBar from '../NavBar/NavBar';
import NonHomeNav from '../NavBar/NonHomeNav';
import { ReactSession } from 'react-client-session';
import { AuthContext } from '../../services/auth.context.js';
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Disclosure, Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react';
import { Bars3Icon, BellIcon, XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';

import './Header.css';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';

const countrySectionStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '125px',
  // backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/Mountin.jpg)`
};

const sectionStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '400px',
  backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/Mountin.jpg)`,
};

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div class='w-full bg-center bg-cover h-[32rem]' style={sectionStyle}>
        <NavBar />
        {/* <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-full h-full"> */}
        <section class=' flex flex-1 justify-center '>
          <div class=' flex flex-col w-auto items-center '>
            <h1 class='header-text text-5xl font-extrabold text-center lg:text-7xl 2xl:text-8xl '>
              <span class='text-transparent bg-gradient-to-br bg-clip-text  from-blue-500 via-pink-500 to-red-500 dark:from-teal-200 dark:via-indigo-300 dark:to-sky-500 '>
                Your World
              </span>
            </h1>

            <h1 class='text-5xl font-extrabold text-center lg:text-7xl 2xl:text-8xl'>
              <span class='text-transparent bg-gradient-to-tr bg-clip-text from-blue-500 via-pink-500 to-red-500 dark:from-sky-300 dark:via-pink-300 dark:to-red-500'>
                Guide
              </span>
            </h1>
          </div>
        </section>
        {/* </div> */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const navigation = [
  // { name: 'Home', href: '/', current: true },
];

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ');
}

export const CountryHeader = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated, onLogout } = useContext(AuthContext);

  // const user = JSON.parse(ReactSession.get('userId'))
  //   console.log(user)

  // const username = user.visibleUsername

  return (
    <Disclosure as='nav' style={{ minHeight: '11vh', background: '#826644' }}>
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <div className='mx-auto max-w-7xl px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8'>
            <div className='relative flex h-16 items-center justify-between'>
              <div className='absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden'>
                {/* <img
                  className="block h-8 w-auto lg:hidden"
                  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
                  alt="Your Company"
                /> */}
                <SendIcon className='h-6 w-6 text-white' />
                <Link href='/'>
                  <strong className='text-xl text-white font-bold'>
                    Geopilot
                  </strong>
                </Link>
                {/* Mobile menu button*/}
                <Disclosure.Button className='inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white'>
                  <span className='sr-only'>Open main menu</span>
                  {open ? (
                    <XMarkIcon className='block h-6 w-6' aria-hidden='true' />
                  ) : (
                    <Bars3Icon className='block h-6 w-6' aria-hidden='true' />
                  )}
                </Disclosure.Button>
              </div>

              {/* <div className="flex ml-96 sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start ">   */}
              <Box marginLeft='34.5em'>
                <div className='hidden sm:ml-6 sm:block'>
                  <div className='flex space-x-4'>
                    {navigation.map((item) => (
                      <Box
                        key={item.name}
                        href={item.href}
                        className={classNames(
                          item.current
                            ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white'
                            : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                          'px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium'
                        )}
                        aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                      >
                        {item.name}
                      </Box>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Box>
              {/* </div> */}
              <div className='absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0'>
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='rounded-full bg-gray-800 p-1 text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800'
                >
                  <span className='sr-only'>View notifications</span>
                  <BellIcon className='h-6 w-6' aria-hidden='true' />
                </button>

                {/* Profile dropdown */}

                {!isAuthenticated ? (
                  <>
                    <Link
                      to='/login'
                      className='hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium'
                    >
                      <Typography color={'white'} fontSize={'14px'}>
                        Login
                      </Typography>
                    </Link>
                    <Link
                      to='/register'
                      className='text-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium'
                    >
                      <Typography color={'white'} fontSize={'14px'}>
                        Sign Up
                      </Typography>
                    </Link>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <Menu as='div' className='relative ml-3'>
                    <div>
                      <Menu.Button className='flex rounded-full bg-gray-800 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800'>
                        <span className='sr-only'>Open user menu</span>
                        <img
                          className='h-8 w-8 rounded-full'
                          src={`https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/initials/.svg`}
                          alt='User profile picture'
                        />
                      </Menu.Button>
                    </div>
                    <Transition
                      as={Fragment}
                      enter='transition ease-out duration-100'
                      enterFrom='transform opacity-0 scale-95'
                      enterTo='transform opacity-100 scale-100'
                      leave='transition ease-in duration-75'
                      leaveFrom='transform opacity-100 scale-100'
                      leaveTo='transform opacity-0 scale-95'
                    >
                      <Menu.Items className='absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-48 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none'>
                        {/* <Menu.Item>
                      {({ active }) => (
                        <a
                          href="#"
                          className={classNames(active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700')}
                        >
                          Your Profile
                        </a>
                      )}
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item>
                      {({ active }) => (
                        <a
                          href="#"
                          className={classNames(active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700')}
                        >
                          Settings
                        </a>
                      )}
                    </Menu.Item> */}
                        <Menu.Item>
                          {({ active }) => (
                            <button
                              onPress={onLogout()}
                              className={classNames(
                                active ? 'bg-grey-100' : '',
                                'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700'
                              )}
                            >
                              Sign out
                            </button>
                          )}
                        </Menu.Item>
                      </Menu.Items>
                    </Transition>
                  </Menu>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <Disclosure.Panel className='sm:hidden'>
            <div className='space-y-1 px-2 pt-2 pb-3'>
              {navigation.map((item) => (
                <Disclosure.Button
                  key={item.name}
                  as='a'
                  href={item.href}
                  className={classNames(
                    item.current
                      ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white'
                      : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                    'block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium'
                  )}
                  aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Disclosure.Button>
              ))}
            </div>
          </Disclosure.Panel>
        </>
      )}
    </Disclosure>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

I tried to adapt the button sizes based on screensize but they still wouldn't work. Even the links do not work.

I was expecting the buttons to at least appear as buttons but they won't

Comment: can you provide a sandbox ?

Comment: Please produce only the part which is causing you the error, instead of the entire code